# Single EXE to Install Python Standalone Executable for Easy Distribution

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

I used Pyinstaller to create a standalone exe file for a PyQt project. I did not use the single file option because the exe that is created with the single file option takes too long to open. Therefore, Pyinstaller created a dist folder that contains a bunch of files including my program.exe file. I would now like to create a setup.exe file that will place the contents of my dist folder in the program directory and create a shortcut in the start menu and on the desktop. I want it to be super simple for the user. Maybe like the setup.exe files that you get when you download a program from CNET. I found Inno-setup, which looks promising. However, I do not know if there any special considerations because the program is a standalone program create from a python/PyQt program. Thanks! Anyone have experience with this task? Is there a program everyone is using for this task that I do not know about?

Answer (score 0):

Inno-Setup or NSIS are probably the easiest to use. You just tell them what files to include and where to put them and then they will create a nice installer for you. I wrote a short tutorial on my experiences using InnoSetup that you might find helpful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/08/27/packaging-wxpymail-for-distribution/

Note that this tutorial was based around a wxPython app I wrote, but the concepts are the same.